# Talend - tSalesforceInput component only returns null results on Custom Objects

Tags: salesforce, talend, soql

I am using Talend to extract data from Salesforce, but no matter what i try, when i try to pull data from a custom object, all i ever get is a null value.

I am using Talend 6.1, and the version of salesforce is 33.

I have created a simple tsalesForceInput to tlogrow routine, but it isn't working.

In the tSalesforceInput I have the following options selected:

Module: Custom Object
Custom Object Name: LLC_BI__Loan__c
Manual input of SOQL query: True

```
 select 
 LLC_BI__Account__c
 FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c
```

Please can anyone help me? I have checked, and there is data populated in this field for each record returned, but it will only ever display null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was regarding the schema not matching exactly on the tLogrow. Once this was amended to have column as LLC_BI__Account__c it worked (I think i had missed the double underscore).